# No internet after adapter changed name to enp3s0 from eth0 after upgrading to SSD

Tags: networking

I'm updating from a HDD to a SSD and have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on the new drive. Since installation, I have no internet connection.  A bit of digging showed this to be because the network address has changed from eth0 to enp3s0 which, I believe, is a Predictable Network Address.  I can find a few solutions to this problem but they all concentrate on overriding the change and reverting to eth0. If the change of address has some advantages, surely we should be accepting the new addresses. Is there a way to do this?

**Edit.**  Thanks for replies so far and apologies for the sparse info, I'm new to this. I'm updating my **desktop** system on which I've been happily running Ubuntu 16.04 without problems since its release. In order to post this, I've reconfigured it back to the old HDD as I have no other means of connecting to the internet. Looking at the network diagnostics, it seems geared towards WiFi so is not much use to me. Kyle H, thanks for your comment but it is way over my head. Comment from Soren A seems to be on the right track but I don't appear to have a network manager app.
I'm not after a solution to the 'problem' of the changed address - I understand why it has happened and I understand there are several workarounds to 'fix' it. I just feel that we should be accepting the change to predictive addressing and want to know how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue and lead to a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just configure enp3s0 from the network-manager app ?

Comment: Can you connect to the wired network, do you receive an ip once connected? Show this with <code>ip addr</code> in the terminal. If this works, can you ping your default gateway? What about 8.8.8.8? Then what about pinging google.com? If you reach here, then the network should be working. What step fails?